# This question is not duplicate so consider re-opening it

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions

I asked this question ["The software on this computer is up to date" while upgrading 12.10 to 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315613/cant-update-12-10-to-13-04) I have this unique error "The software on this computer is up to date" I couldn't find its solution anywhere. However question was closed as duplicate of [How do I upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279620/how-do-i-upgrade-from-12-10-to-13-04). Consider re-opening the question.

Comment: Yeah I thought that was fair enough. Reopened.